# My computer won't let me render with eevee?

Tags: rendering

Why does eevee insta crash Blender whenever I render anything on my Mac mini?

I have 8GB RAM and I am using 3 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i7, is my RAM just too dinky to be able to render using eevee??

Comment: In my experience Macs don't behave reliably with Eevee. See my previous similar question here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/175510/does-eevee-in-2-82-work-on-macbookpro-intel-integrated-graphics-cards which never received an official answer but a few comments.

Comment: Another user said he was able to render in Eevee with GPU graphics card. But I have tried on CPU and GPU Macbooks with the same result. I can render only very simple scenes in Eevee, with more complex scenes, the image will render in the render window and stay for a second, but then oddly it cuts to a grey image after Compositing. Oddly I can render animation in Eevee, but I haven't tried highres animations, although it will render scenes as animations that I am not able to render as still images in Eevee at very low res. It remains a mystery to me and potentially a bug on Macs running Blender

Comment: Ussually unsupported graphics card, see https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/ At home I have old iMac 2009 that render white in eevee or crash on Shadow or Cavity overlay from 2.82. iMacs 2013, 2017, 2020 at work works for me.

Comment: These comments are helpful thank you, I was sure it was my RAM that was the issue but I am able to render (slowly) using any other renderer in Blender no crashing.

Comment: I keep looking at possibly using eGPU with the Mac mini but I think it may be too advanced for me to make it work properly. I also don't know if it would solve the issue of eevee just flat out not working.